# What does it mean by a variable declared by let can't be redeclared in javascript?

Tags: javascript, var, let

When I search for difference between let and var in javascript it says variable declared by let can't be redeclared but variables declared by var can be redeclared but does this line mean?

Comment: Try: `let foo; let foo;`…

Answer (score 0):

Well hello Vinay Singla the thing is when you use `let` you do not have to redeclare it.
Otherwise an error will pop and a new `let` is very similar when you declare variables in python .
Code you wrote will cause an error